# error find-up@4.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8". Ember js + Heroku Deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, ember.js, ember-cli, package.json

- Ember-CLI:- 3.4.3
- Node:- 6.9.5
- Yarn:- 1.9.4

During the deployment of my ember project on Heroku, I got this error here is log. 
We have find-up version 3.0.0 but during deployment, it is still trying to download find-up@4.1.0 if anyone have an idea about this to ignore download of the latest version of find-up or any solution so comment it here it will be very helpful thanks in advance.

```
error find-up@4.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ember CLI app.
 !     Push failed
```

**Here is my Package.json**

```
   {
  "name": "tabsys-client",
  "version": "2.13.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Web and mobile client for Activate Universal",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "lint:js": "eslint ./*.js app config lib server tests",
    "start": "ember serve",
    "test": "ember test",
    "postinstall": "node -e \"try { require('fs').symlinkSync(require('path').resolve('node_modules/@bower_components'), 'bower_components', 'junction') } catch (e) { }\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bower_components/FakeXMLHttpRequest": "trek/FakeXMLHttpRequest#^1.4.0",
    "@bower_components/Faker": "Marak/Faker.js#~3.1.0",
    "@bower_components/d3": "mbostock-bower/d3-bower#^4.11.0",
    "@bower_components/d3-tip": "Caged/d3-tip#^0.7.1",
    "@bower_components/dexie": "dfahlander/dexie.js#^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@bower_components/dialog-polyfill": "GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill#^0.4.7",
    "@bower_components/ember-qunit-notifications": "dockyard/ember-qunit-notifications#0.1.0",
    "@bower_components/highcharts-custom-events": "blacklabel/custom_events#2.1.4",
    "@bower_components/leaflet": "Leaflet/Leaflet#^1.0.0",
    "@bower_components/material-design-lite": "google/material-design-lite#^1.2.1",
    "@bower_components/pretender": "trek/pretender#~1.1.0",
    "@bower_components/qunit-notifications": "dockyard/qunit-notifications#~0.1.0",
    "@bower_components/route-recognizer": "tildeio/route-recognizer#~0.1.1",
    "@bower_components/sauce-material-design": "sauce-consultants/sauce-material-design#1.0.0rc8",
    "ember-cli": "^3.4.3",
    "object.values": "^1.0.4",
    "replace": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "broccoli-funnel": "2.0.1",
    "corber": "1.3.10",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^7.1.2",
    "ember-cli-clock": "2.1.1",
    "ember-cli-dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.1",
    "ember-cli-fastclick": "1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-favicon": "1.0.0-beta.4",
    "ember-cli-geo": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.8.2",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "3.3.1",
    "ember-cli-nouislider": "^0.14.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.1.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "ember-cli-sass": "7.1.3",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-composability": "0.3.7",
    "ember-concurrency": "0.7.17",
    "ember-cordova-events": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cordova-platform": "^0.1.0",
    "ember-cordova-splash": "0.1.4",
    "ember-crumbly": "2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "ember-data": "~2.18.0",
    "ember-data-url-templates": "0.2.0",
    "ember-drag-drop": "^0.6.2",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-file-upload": "2.0.0-beta.24",
    "ember-highcharts": "0.5.4",
    "ember-i18n": "5.0.2",
    "ember-inflector": "2.0.1",
    "ember-leaflet": "3.0.9",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-local-storage": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "ember-material-lite": "0.2.5",
    "ember-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-modal-dialog": "^2.4.1",
    "ember-moment": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "ember-new-computed": "1.0.3",
    "ember-pikaday": "2.2.2",
    "ember-power-select": "1.9.6",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-route-action-helper": "2.0.6",
    "ember-sauce-material-design": "sauce-consultants/ember-sauce-material-design.git#1.0.0rc18",
    "ember-sauce-toolkit": "sauce-consultants/ember-sauce-toolkit#0.1.5",
    "ember-select-box": "1.1.14",
    "ember-service-worker": "0.6.6",
    "ember-service-worker-asset-cache": "0.6.1",
    "ember-service-worker-index": "0.6.1",
    "ember-sortable": "1.9.3",
    "ember-source": "~2.18.0",
    "ember-tether": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "2.0.0",
    "ember-web-app": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.0.0",
    "emberx-file-input": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^5.0.0",
    "highcharts": "^7.0.0",
    "liquid-fire": "0.27.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.5.0",
    "pikaday": "1.6.1",
    "smd-colors": "sauce-consultants/smd-colors.git#25e787d8a85af98c60ec3482e0534ea8aaab1208",
    "torii": "0.9.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.5",
    "yarn": "1.9.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that you say, that you have `find-up@3.0.0` on development but on deployment it tries to install `find-up@4.1.0`. That's very strange cause the versions should be locked down in `yarn.lock` and ensured to install the exact same. Don't you commit the `yarn.lock`? Or do you run `yarn install` with `--no-lockfile` or some other flag that may causing this on deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the issue of "replace": "^1.1.1" under dependencies in package.json so I just lock replace version by adding this "replace": "1.1.1" and it works for me thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 6):

> if anyone have an idea about this to ignore download of the latest version of find-up

I don't see find-up in your `package.json`. Is it dependency of some other dependency?

Anyway, I suggest to lock all dependency versions in `package.json` in order to avoid any surprises (these surprises usually are costly). To do this, you need to remove all `^` and `~`. For example, `"highcharts": "7.0.0",` instead of `"highcharts": "^7.0.0",`. You need to run yarn install after that to install correct versions of dependencies and update `yarn.lock` file.

Also, `yarn install --ignore-engines` should ignore node version checks, if previous solution does not help.

Comment: What is the reason to log the version of direct dependencies in `package.json` when you have a `yarn.lock` that ensures consistent versions between installs for direct and indirect dependencies?

Comment: @jelhan I have been working more with npm than yarn but AFAIK, both can update dependencies during `install` or `add` commands. [Yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/) even suggest to use `--frozen-lockfile` to prevent lockfile update. Locking dependencies in `package.json` ensures that direct dependencies would never be updated accidentally during routine workIt is especially important given old ember version (I see 2.18 here). Sometimes minor update in one of dependencies could cost couple of hours to figure out why things are broken out of sudden

Comment: @jelhan also, lockfile is for yarn/npm. It is big and hard to trace changes when needed. Package.json is for devs. It is readable and its easier to trace who changed dependencies versions and why.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev Yes it is not in package.json but it is the dependency of the Ember-CLI.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev I prefer to check in CI that the `yarn.lock` is not out of sync. Locking down direct dependencies in `package.json` breaks `yarn upgrade`. Actually this just makes upgrades of dependencies way more difficult cause you don't profit from semantic versioning anymore. NPM is another topic cause it hasn't supported locking down dependencies very well for a long time...

Comment: @jelhan minor upgrade in 3rd-party library may easily break an app. It should be difficult for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn tells you that the npm package `find-up` is expecting a Node version greater or equal 8. Accordingly to your question you are using Node 6.

End of life for node 6 was on 30 April 2019. Even Node 8 not supported anymore since end of last year.

You should upgrade to a supported version of Node to resolve that issue. Node 10 and 12 are active LTS versions. Node 13 is the current latest release. You could find an overview of Node versions and their support at https://github.com/nodejs/Release.

Answer (score 0):

please upgrade your node version to last stable version of nodejs, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a higher version of node.js installed on your system.

In this case, node.js v8 or above should be installed in the system.